# Insufficient privilege in 'Article Management' tab

Tags: record-access-level

A user is trying to modify the existing article. For this the user clicks the 'Article Management' tab. However, following error is received:

Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

User's profile has these permission:
Manage Articles
Manage Salesforce Knowledge
CRED Permission on All Article Type

In the user's profile Custom Field Level Security (for the corresponding 'object' of each article type shown in the profile permission list), all fields are visible except auto number.

Is there any other set up that is missing that is causing the error?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you didn't check "Knowledge User" checkbox in corresponding User's settings.